# Sonarqube 7.7 installation in Windows

Tags: runtime-error

Got the following error:

2019.04.25 22:53:05 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2019.04.25 22:53:05 ERROR web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] Fail to start web server
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:427)
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:61)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:51)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:113)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:100)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:91)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9000]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
2019.04.25 22:53:05 WARN  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:65)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:51)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:113)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:100)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:91)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:427)
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:61)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9000]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 9 common frames omitted

Answer (score 1):

Edit $SONAR_HOME/conf/sonar.properties and set following property to your real IP:
sonar.web.host=$YOUR_REAL_IP

Comment: Thanks for your reply - could you add your reasoning for suggesting this solution?

Comment: Default value for this property is 192.0.0.1. In some cases (like bad network config), localhost can not be resolved to this IP address and setting real sonar server IP could resolve this problem.